# Extracting thin object from image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, imagefilter

My task is to separate green stems from the desired image, for which i use Frangi filter based approach.However Frangi filter also outputs several leaf edges apart from the shoots alone. Is there a way to improve this result ?

Here is the image after HSV color segmentation 
[image]

Here is the frangi output after thresholding [image]

Here is the frangi code :

```
options=struct('FrangiScaleRange', [5 10], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 1, 'FrangiBetaOne', 0.5,...
    'FrangiBetaTwo', 10, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',false);


   [outIm,whatScale,Direction] = FrangiFilter2D(double(img_frangi), options);
```

Comment: Are you using the MATLAB FrangiFilter2D function found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter)? You should cite this source, it would be helpful for someone who is not familiar with the function to read the code-behind.

Comment: I think you took the right first step: HSV color segmentation. Maybe, instead of the Frangi 2D filter, you could try using [MATLAB's Hough transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) to extract small line segments (if we can consider the shoots as roughly vertical lines).

Comment: I would further suggest that you try taking a Binary Edge image and then use information you obtain after applying a [Radon transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/_f21-15119.html) to locate the shoots (similar to the Hough transform). The benefit of this approach is that you'd have an intermediate step of using the Radon transform result to find the lines (i.e., shoots) and their orientations before you extract them from the Binary Edge image. This way, if some of the detected lines are in the wrong orientation (not vertical enough), then you ignore those false matches :)

Comment: If you'd like another example of how to use the Hough transform in MATLAB to detect lines in an image, you can find some code (that I presume is working... looks alright to me at a glance) at the 9th message of 9 in [this MATLAB question thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/244676).

Comment: @VladislavMartin I am already using Hough Transform on top of Frangi output. Using Hough before the Frangi filter gives too many false positives. Having said that, thank you for your input. I really appreciate it. If you have any other suggestions for me, i would be happy to try them.

Comment: I see. You should edit your question to reflect each of the steps you take to get from the HSV segmentation to the final B/W image after the Frangi 2D filter so that other people might suggest other approaches. It might be helpful to see how you use the peaks you get as a result of the Hough transform - that's the step that is giving you so many false positives and that's the step that probably needs the most tweaking! I'll post something if I get a better idea of how to solve it... stumped for now